# function converges uniformly

Tags: real-analysis

Let $G(x,\alpha) = \ln (\alpha^2 - \sin^2 x )$. where $\alpha > 1$ and $x \in [0, \pi/2]$

> #### Claim: $G(x,\alpha)$ converges uniformly to $\ln (1 - \sin^2 x) $ as $\alpha \to 1^+ $ on $[0, \pi/2]$

Let $\epsilon > 0$ be given. I need to find $\delta > 0$  such that if $\alpha-1< \delta$ and, then

$$ | \ln (\alpha^2 - \sin^2 x ) - \ln (1 - \sin^2 x) |  < \epsilon$$

I know I want bound

$$ \left| \ln \left( \frac{ \alpha^2 - \sin^2 }{\cos^2 x } \right) \right| $$

but here I am stuck. How can I estimate this in order to find my desired $\delta$?

Comment: What about $x\to \frac \pi2$.

Comment: This is false: there is no uniform convergence because $$\lim_{x \to \pi /2^-} \ln (1- \sin^2 x)= -\infty$$ However, you have uniform convergence on every compact set $K \subset [0, \pi /2 )$.